# Add template to Zabbix host using C# ZabbixAPI

Tags: c#, api, nuget, zabbix

I'm trying to add a template to a host in Zabbix (3.0) using [this](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Zabbix/) specific nuget package (version 1.1.3).

While I'm able to get/delete specific hosts and templates I'm unable to update one.
Looking at Zabbix [documentation for updating hosts](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/3.0/manual/api/reference/host/update) I found this description of *templates* parameter:

> Templates to replace the currently linked templates. Templates that are not passed are only unlinked.

So I gathered that I should add a template to *parentTemplates* property in a host object and the pass the host to the *Update* method of *HostService*:

```
Context context = new Context();

var templateService = new TemplateService(context);
Template template = templateService.Get(new { host = "Template_test" }).First();

var hostService = new HostService(context);
Host host = hostService.GetByName("testhost");

host.parentTemplates.Add(template);
hostService.Update(host);
```

(Note that `Context context = new Context()` will work as I'm using a .config file.)

After compiling and executing, the program runs with no errors, but the host is still templateless.

Has anyone tried this before?
Am I missing something obvious?

---

Notes on Zabbix configuration:

- *Template_test* is a valid and existing template
- *testhost* is an existing host
- Zabbix user that I'm using in this demonstration has Zabbix Super Admin privileges to eliminate issues with permissions.

=== EDIT ===

There four requests being made:

- user.login (OK)
- template.get (OK)
- host.get (OK)
- host.update (NOK)

The last one is causing problems. The full request is [here](https://pastebin.com/wrAZku0m).

The response:

> {"jsonrpc":"2.0","result":{"hostids":["10135"]},"id":"ca04d839-e6ec-4017-81b0-cc7f8e01fcfc"}

The request is needlessly big. I'll check if i can trim it down a bit.

Comment: Can you post the raw JSON that is sent to Zabbix API and returned by it?

Comment: @Richlv Here you go. The generated request is a disaster...

Comment: It's a bug. Library uses wrong parameter name. More details in this [issue](https://github.com/HenriqueCaires/ZabbixApi/issues/50).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment of the question: the parameter has an invalid name.
This comes from the fact that Zabbix *host.get* method returns templates in *parentTemplates* property, while *host.update* uses *templates*.

The creator of the NuGet did not account for this, so I created a new [issue](https://github.com/HenriqueCaires/ZabbixApi/issues/50) in his project.

I managed to get my code working by deriving a class from *Host*:

```
private class NewHost : Host
{
    public IList<Template> templates { get; set; }
}
```

Then i can make a request using this class:

```
Context context = new Context();

var templateService = new TemplateService(context);
Template template = templateService.Get(new { host = "Template_test" }).First();

var hostService = new HostService(context);
Host host = hostService.GetByName("testhost");

host.parentTemplates.Add(template);

var newhost = new NewHost
{
    Id = host.Id,
    templates = host.parentTemplates
}

hostService.Update(newhost);
```

Thanks to this not only a proper name is used, but also the request body is way smaller.